# Extracting json retruns null

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have This query in snowflake :

```
  SELECT
    S.src:auditoriumName::STRING               AS auditoriumName,
    S.src:country::STRING                      AS country,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.src:customizedFields::STRING, '["', ''), '"]', '') AS customizedFields_title,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GET_PATH(f.value, '$.title'), '"', ''), '<p>', ''),'/<p>','') AS customizedFields_title1,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GET_PATH(f.value, '$.value'), '"', ''), '<p>', ''),'/<p>','') AS customizedFields_value,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(S.src:date::STRING)           AS date 
  FROM Source_Data AS S,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => S.src:customizedFields) AS f
```

here column **customizedFields_title** has values such as : `[{"title":"<p>Yes, please, I would like to receive the newsletter</p>","value":"true"}]`

I am trying to extract this and put the record in **customizedFields_title1** and **customizedFields_value** but here I am getting NULL
[image]

could some one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an error on `GET_PATH`, Try this instead :

```
 SELECT
    S.src:auditoriumName::STRING               AS auditoriumName,
    S.src:country::STRING                      AS country,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.src:customizedFields::STRING, '["', ''), '"]', '') AS customizedFields_title,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(GET_PATH(f.value, '"title"')::STRING, '"', ''), '<p>', ''),'/<p>','') AS customizedFields_title1,
    GET_PATH(f.value, '"value"')::STRING AS customizedFields_value,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(S.src:date::STRING)           AS date 
  FROM Source_Data AS S,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => S.src:customizedFields) AS f
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this code may be the source of your problem. Consider adding values of these codes to your result set to investigate if they are returning something or not.

```
GET_PATH(f.value, '$.title')
GET_PATH(f.value, '$.value')
```